# Format of the git diff is not correct when stored in Bash variable

Tags: bash, git

I want to calculate this in bash file

```
files : {
          {
             file {
                     name: "Bla,java"
                     line_changes : [45,146,14]
                  }
          } 
          {
             file {
                     name: "Foo.java"
                     line_changed : [7,8,9,10]
                  }
          }
       }
```

so I have this

```
gitOutput=$(git diff origin/master..origin/mybranch)
echo $gitOuput
```

My problem is :

The output is sooo, not formatted.

Everything is in one line

I cannot parse it logically...

Like Split by \n or split by "diff --git" etc

Also there are no new line .
So if there are some, it doesnot make sense.

So I want to know, is there any pretty format option for git diff

[UPDATE]

I have tried this weird approach

```
git diff origin/master..origin/mybranch > data.txt
data=$(cat data.txt)
```

Output is :
The data.txt is absolutely perfect
but the data var. is all messed up...

is it something related to IFS ???

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you should add quotes:

```
gitOutput="$(git diff origin/master..origin/mybranch)"
echo "$gitOuput"
```

so that line returns are kept as is. This is usually what you want to do in a general matter when having variables in shell.

For a detailed explanation on the use of quotes, see
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary

Comment: This is perfect. Can you explain a bit how this "" makes a difference ?

Comment: @AkhilSoni The link in the answer explains it